# Navigation bar changing between pages

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have built a navbar for a website, and for some reason when I go from the home page to the gallery page the font size changes for the nav items. I even have a class that has set it to 1.7em. Im not sure what exactly could be causing this.

Images:

Indexpage

[image]

gallerypage

[image]

This is the index page:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-white d-flex justify-content-center navbar-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
        aria-controls="navbar-dropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon d-lg-none"></span>
    </button>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link nvm-link current-link" href="index.html"> NVM </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link non-active-link" href="gallery.html"> GALLERY </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link non-active-link" href="shop.html"> SHOP </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link non-active-link" href="#"> MUSIC </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link non-active-link" href="#"> CONTACT </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid full-height">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="home-article">
                <h2 class="home-header flexFont">WHO THE HELL ARE WE?</h2>
                <p class="text-indent main-text"> Hell is full, of all the torturing, screaming, killing, fire,
                    smoke, and poker games a demon could ask for. Unforunately, Satan had no interest in giving us
                    what we needed to have a successful business in the underworld, and most of the other demons
                    laughed in our faces or ignored us. </p>
                <p class="text-indent main-text"> Nobody in hell cared about us, and why would they? It's fucking
                    hell, but me and my cool ass friends knew we deserved more than that. So, we sought out to find
                    the prophesied portal to the surface realm. And guess what bitches, WE FOUND IT! </p>
                <p class="text-indent main-text"> After we celebrated, we closed the portal to prevent any lames
                    from rising above and stealing our awesome idea, We were gonna make this business happen in a
                    world where people care about looking badass(almost everone in hell is pretty badass).</p>
                <p class="text-indent main-text"> After we arrived, you humans didn't really take kindly to a bunch
                    of unholy beasts trying to sell you shit, understandable. So we did some research, removed our
                    horns, and made ourselves some awesome masks. <br> NOW WE LOOK LIKE YOU! BOOM! </p>
                <p class="text-indent main-text"> You're welcome, it took a lot of soul for us to demote ourselves
                    to your standard so you could buy our gold, so have some fucking empathy. Look at our art, buy
                    our clothes and other cool ass merchandise, sign up for our newsletter too while you're at it.
                </p>
                <p class="text-indent main-text"> Don't worry. We don't want to kill you, without you we serve no
                    purpose. We just want to spread our noise surface-wide(and then maybe eat your soul, if you're a
                    poser). </p>
                <p class="text-indent main-text bottom-text"> Welcome to <a class="text-red" href="#"> NVM </a>, the
                    home of the designer demons.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <img class="demon-pic" src="" alt="IMAGE OF THE SEVEN OF US DRAWN AS OUR DEMONS">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the gallery page:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-white d-flex justify-content-center navbar-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
        aria-controls="navbar-dropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon d-lg-none"></span>
    </button>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link nvm-link current-link" href="index.html"> NVM </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link non-active-link" href="gallery.html"> GALLERY </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link non-active-link" href="shop.html"> SHOP </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link non-active-link" href="#"> MUSIC </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link non-active-link" href="#"> CONTACT </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi thecoolfroguy, welcome to Stack Overflow! You shouldn't post your entire code. You can read this: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi thecoolfroguy, Can you post some screenshots as well pointing out the exact issues?

Comment: We can't confirm anything from here unless you show us the exact issue, I can see you have a missing end `</body>` tag in your gallery page code.

Comment: links to images posted

Comment: Do you have some different css loading on these pages?  I am not sure how you are managing your styles.